# Issue with my Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm still learning the language so please be indulgent.

The condition related to my START variable in the following code never triggers, and I can't figure out why. That part is supposed to execute if the current line starts with "80/" and the preceding line starts with a semicolon and then a space. Probably a synthax error or some such. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

>"%~dpn1_2.txt" (
    FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%j in ('find /V /N "" %1') DO (
        SET "currentLine=%%k"
        SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        IF "!currentLine:~0,2!"=="; " (
            SET START=1
        ) ELSE IF "!currentLine:~0,3!"=="80/" (
            IF "!START!"=="1" (
                SET "currentLine=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3,5!  !currentLine:~18!"
                SET START=
            ) ELSE (
                SET string=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3,4!
                FIND "!string!" labels.txt > nul
                IF !errorlevel! EQU 0 (
                    SET "currentLine=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3,5!  !currentLine:~18!"
                ) ELSE (
                    SET "currentLine=         !currentLine:~18!"
                )
            )
        )
        ECHO(!currentline!
        ENDLOCAL
    )
)
```

Comment: There's no `ELSE IF` in batch

Comment: @SomethingDark, `else if` does work fine...

Comment: Sheldon, the problem is that for each line, you're doing `setlocal`, a bunch of other crap, then `endlocal` as the parsing for that particular line is complete.  When you read the next line, `endlocal` will have purged any variables you've set, including `!START!`. Easiest solution might simply be to run the entire script with delayed expansion enabled rather than toggling it, unless you're concerned with clobbering exclamation marks. If you are, you could also use a series of `call`s with doubled percents to delay expansion. There are other tricks you could use if that one is not palatable.

Comment: You could replace `endlocal` by `if defined START (endlocal & set START=1) else endlocal`, so `START` is transferred to the environment *after* `endlocal`; or you could omit `START` completely, state something like `set "previousLine=%%k"` after `endlocal` and procesa both `previousLine` and `currentLine` at once with nested `if` queries...

Comment: @SomethingDark, I disagree; after `else` you can place `if` just like every other command also; `if else` can even improve legibility of code as the alternative might be `if ... goto` constructs which may be harder to understand; the most important precondition for readability of (nested) `if`/`else` queries is proper indentation of code...

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Yes, I do need to preserve exclamation marks. The "previousLine" suggestion worked. For some reason, I couldn't get START to be cleared while trying to implement your other suggestion, aschipfl.

Comment: Yes, that is because I forgot to reset `START` in the `else` clause; this should be correct now: `if defined START (endlocal & set START=1) else (endlocal & set START=)`...

Comment: I've posted the updated code as an answer, but this takes forever to complete because my file has over 30,000 lines. Any suggestions to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

>"%~dpn1_2.txt" (
  FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%j in ('find /V /N "" %1') DO (
    SET "currentLine=%%k"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    IF "!currentLine:~0,3!"=="80/" (
      IF "!previousLine:~0,2!"=="; " (
        SET "currentLine=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3,5!  !currentLine:~18!"
      ) ELSE (
          SET string=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3,4!
          FIND "!string!" labels.txt > nul
          IF !errorlevel! EQU 0 (
            SET "currentLine=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3,5!  !currentLine:~18!"
          ) ELSE (
              SET "currentLine=         !currentLine:~18!"
          )
        )
    )
    ECHO(!currentline!
    ENDLOCAL
    SET "previousLine=%%k"
  )
)
```